# ios binaural audio unit

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

i'm new in audiounit.

I'm confused to generate binaural tone filter, I was create two sound with left only and right only sound and add filter kAudioUnitSubType_LowPassFilter for each sound. When playing, i'm using UISlider to change kLowPassParam_CutoffFrequency for each player, this is a code :

```
  Float32 value = slider.value; //only 160-190 hz
    AEAudioUnitFilter *toneLeft = [self.sound objectForKey:@"binaural_left"];
    AEAudioUnitFilter *toneRight = [self.sound objectForKey:@"binaural_right"];
    if(toneLeft && toneRight){
        Float32 leftFreq = value - self.rangeSlider.value;  // i have two slider, for frequency and range
        Float32 rightFreq = value + self.rangeSlider.value;
        AudioUnitSetParameter(toneLeft.audioUnit,
                              kLowPassParam_CutoffFrequency,
                              kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                              0,
                              leftFreq,
                              0);

        AudioUnitSetParameter(toneRight.audioUnit,
                              kLowPassParam_CutoffFrequency,
                              kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                              0,
                              rightFreq,
                              0);
}
```

but when sound played, i didn't hear a binaural, only the frequency changes.

I got an idea from : [Idea](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WI4fbPl7--s)

I'm using [theamazingaudioengine.com](http://theamazingaudioengine.com)  framework.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: problem solved, take a look to http://forum.theamazingaudioengine.com/discussion/492/create-a-dynamic-binaural-tone :D